# dynamically getIdByName

Tags: dynamic, getelementbyid

I have a series of 20 pictures showing on my page all with unique ids and values. each picture is contained in a td. I want to get the value of the td that was clicked. I have tried everything but it doesn't work the way it should. The value is always undefined.Why? Here is a sample code:

```
<?php
$html='';

for($i=0; $i < 20; $i++){
$html .= "<td id='tdName' value='$i'></td>";

}
?>
<html>
<body>
<table><tr>
 <?php echo $html; ?>
</tr>
</table>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$('#tdName').on('click', function() {
     tdValue =  document.getElementById('tdName').value;
alert(tdValue);
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

How do I get the unique value each time the user clicks a td? I don't want to have 20 click functions either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to grab the right target to pull the value. "e" is an event object jQuery passes, which contains 'currentTarget' as a property. That selects the one you clicked, then you can pull its 'value' attribute which you set manually at the top.

```
$('#tdName').on('click', function(e) {
  var value = $(e.currentTarget).attr('value');
});
```

Comment: This seems to only work when I click the first td and it gives me 0. When I click any other td I don't get an alert at all. Do you know why? Thank you

Comment: How would I get the value for the second td that was clicked. They all have the same id name is that a problem?

Comment: To let you know, by refering to the id '#tdName' did create a problem because there was more then  one. I changed it and it works now . I will update the answer. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Yes - Ids are *unique*, that is the primary point of an id. Never make the same id twice.

Answer (score 0):

In my case since each td has an id of tdName I had to change the click function to:

```
  $('td').on('click', function(e) {
   var value = $(e.currentTarget).attr('value');
 });
```

So now it works. Great!!